# Need advice with batch, using cmd/psexec

Tags: variables, cmd, psexec

I have fully working batch file, that I use to copy n then run BCU utility on remote computer, with variable that is set in the beginning %MyPC% and then used across whole script.

**My question is, is it possible to use list with computer names, instead of single one?**

I tried to use set and for, with no success.

```
@echo off
echo.
set instpath = %~s0..
cls
:input
for /f %%a in (zarizeni.txt) do set MyPC=%MyPC% %%a

cls
mkdir \\%MyPC%\c$\Tempbios


copy BCU.EXE \\%MyPC%\C$\Tempbios
copy psexec.EXE \\%MyPC%\C$\Tempbios

echo Soubory zkopirovany /pokud nevidis 0 ci chybu


@echo off
title HP BIOS Tool by JN
:home
cls
echo.
echo   VYBER U CEHO ZJISTUJES USB BOOT ENABLE/DISABLE
echo ==================================================
echo.
echo 1) Notebook info
echo 2) PC info
echo 3) Nejsem si jist
echo 4) Kompletni log
echo 5) Ulozit log
echo 6) Exit
echo.
echo ==================================================
echo.


set /p web=Zadej volbu a potvrd:
if "%web%"=="1" goto 1
if "%web%"=="2" goto 2
if "%web%"=="3" goto 3
if "%web%"=="4" goto 4
if "%web%"=="5" goto 5
if "%web%"=="6" exit
goto home

Choice /C 12345 /M "USB/STORAGE BOOT INFO - Notebook[1] nebo PC[2] | Nejsem         si jist [3] Kompletni BIOS log [4] | Ulozeni logu [5] ?
If Errorlevel 5 Goto 5
If Errorlevel 4 Goto 4
If Errorlevel 3 Goto 3
If Errorlevel 2 Goto 2
If ErrorLevel 1 Goto 1

Goto End

:5
cls
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getconfig
Goto End

:4
cls    
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /get >>     "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
Goto End


:3    
cls
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getvalue:"USB Storage Boot" >>     "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getvalue:"USB device Boot" >>     "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getvalue:"Removable Media Boot" >> "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
Goto End

:2
cls
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getvalue:"Removable Media Boot" >> "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
Goto End

:1
cls
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getvalue:"USB Storage Boot" >> "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
psexec.exe \\%MyPC% C:\Tempbios\BCU.exe /getvalue:"USB device Boot" >>     "\\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%MyPC%.txt"
:End


pause


echo : LOG je ulozen na \\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\%.txt
start \\czcscdeploy31\Kopirovani\HPBIOS\
echo : Opravdu chcete po sobe zamest stopy?

del \\%MyPC%\C$\Tempbios
rd \\%MyPC%\C$\Tempbios
```

Comment: remove bash tag please... eye cancer...

Comment: Anyone knows ? :)